# VB for C programmers

Tags: c, vb.net

Can anyone recommend a good guide to VB.Net for someone having experience/comfortable with C?

I can find Python/Java/Lua for C programmers had have used them earlier, but am unable to find anything for C programmers moving to VB.Net

(I'll be moving from using C/C++ with gcc/g++ to VB.Net on VS 2010)

Comment: Can I ask why you prefer to move to VB.NET over C#?

Comment: Our college has a compulsory course for ASP.NET using VB.NET. VB.Net is being taught in the college, but in an extremely boring way (they are explaining the difference between an int and float, arrays and matrices,etc. all over again) Because of this it becomes difficult to extract the relevant parts (I have to listen to the whole lecture just to end up with 2-3 lines of new knowledge). SO, I would prefer something which would point me to the differences between C and VB

Comment: @Akash - Are you new to programming or something?  It sounds like you should pay attention to everything at this point.

Comment: @Ramhound , I'm not very new to programming (have been programming in C for the last 5 years). Because of this, I've studied the same things so many times, I just tend to zone out when the same stuff is taught yet again

Comment: Finding it rather interesting that someone chose to downvote a 3 year old question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find many ressources getting you from C to VB.Net, but you will find lots of them comparing C# and VB.NET. And as C# has its roots in C/C++/Java, it might be easier for you to read those kind of comparisons ([here](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) for example) to get a quick handle on the most common keywords and structures. After that, just try to build projects, with [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express). There are tons of tutorials out there that take only a few hours, and will give you a good sense of the language that should be enough to be at ease during your future course.

Note : As you mentionned that your course will be about asp.net, vb.net will not be the only language to get a handle on. Javascript will be involved as well.

Comment: @Downvoter: why the downvote ?

Comment: Thanks, that comparison was what I needed. (Ideally comparing with C, but since that seems to be non existant, C# is understandable enough as well)

Answer (score 6):

The best place to start is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/default).  They have a bunch of "How Do I .." [videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb466226.aspx), sample [applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ekc8at3.aspx), and [walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4y3z34.aspx).

My suggestion is just to spend some time there and then start writing something.  When you have some specific questions pop up, post them on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).  Good luck.

Comment: MSDN also has tons of code snippets for most of the .NET API.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET was, at least partially, created to bring VB Classic programmers into .NET and object oriented programming.

C# was created, at least partially, to bring Java programmers to .NET.

Now that I've said that you, you can imagine that you won't find many VB.NET books for C programmers.  I took the time to search my Books24x7 account for any resource, but I didn't find anything of value.

Sorry,

Answer (score 0):

There is four parts to this:

- Learning the syntax difference *(easy part)*.
- Learning **OOP** programming paradigm.
- Learning the **.NET** platform (and eco-system)
- Learning the **ASP.NET** framework (MVC/WebForms)

Comment: From the OP's comments, it sounds like he's interested in covering the first two of those points, as a pre-req to a course covering the third and fourth.